# The bean 'hibernateSearchService', defined in class path resource ..., could not be registered

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm following this tutorial to setup search within my application

https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hibernate-search-example/

I think my main issue aims to the class below

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
public class HibernateSearchConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager bentityManager;

    @Bean
    HibernateSearchService hibernateSearchService() {
        HibernateSearchService hibernateSearchService = new HibernateSearchService(bentityManager);
        hibernateSearchService.initializeHibernateSearch();
        return hibernateSearchService;
    }

}
```

When running the application I get

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The bean 'hibernateSearchService', defined in class path resource [myapp/configuration/HibernateSearchConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in file [/home/arya/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite/MyApp/target/classes/myapp/service/HibernateSearchService.class] and overriding is disabled.

Action:

Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

If I remove

```
@Bean
HibernateSearchService hibernateSearchService() {
    HibernateSearchService hibernateSearchService = new HibernateSearchService(bentityManager);
    hibernateSearchService.initializeHibernateSearch();
    return hibernateSearchService;
}
```

From the class above then the application starts fine.

And below is my service class

```
@Service
public class HibernateSearchService {

    @Autowired
    private final EntityManager centityManager;

    @Autowired
    public HibernateSearchService(EntityManager entityManager) {
        super();
        this.centityManager = entityManager;
    }

    public void initializeHibernateSearch() {

        try {
            FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(centityManager);
            fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<Property> fuzzySearch(String searchTerm) {

        FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(centityManager);
        QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Property.class).get();
        Query luceneQuery = qb.keyword().fuzzy().withEditDistanceUpTo(1).withPrefixLength(1).onFields("name")
                .matching(searchTerm).createQuery();

        javax.persistence.Query jpaQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Property.class);

        // execute search

        List<Property> BaseballCardList = null;
        try {
            BaseballCardList = jpaQuery.getResultList();
        } catch (NoResultException nre) {
            ;// do nothing

        }

        return BaseballCardList;

    }
}
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 4):

You are making the same bean twice

once here

```
@Bean
HibernateSearchService hibernateSearchService()
```

and once here

```
@Service
public class HibernateSearchService
```

Either remove one of them or set a name to `@Bean(name="someNameOfYours")` or `@Service("someOtherName")`